# How to solve overlap huds?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Hud: MBProgressHUD or SVProgressHUD

My code is like this:

```
Hud1 shows message: "loading" 

network or other async code, success {

     Hud1 hide
}, failure {

     Hud1 hide

     Hud99 show"error message", hideAfter:2 seconds

}



Hud2 shows message: "loading" 

network or other async code, success {

     Hud2 hide
}, failure {

     Hud1 hide
     Hud99 show"error message", hideAfter:2 seconds

}

..........
```

Sometimes, I have to request two backend data at the same time.

In this scenario, I face a problem that the Huds are overlapping, the color of Huds get dark. More Huds, more dark.

Is there a way to show only one hud? I want to find the best practice to fix this question.

Comment: Have you tried the `popActivity` method https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/blob/master/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h#L141 ?

Comment: Just create an extension, and define a custom method to dismiss it before displaying it.

Comment: Please do not add voting commentary in your posts. It is understood that question authors may/should upvote, but don't use it as a way of requesting free labour.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

```
extension UIView {
    func showHUD(title: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self, animated: true)
            hud.label.text = title
        }
    }
    
    func hideHUD() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Either use above approach or create a class for Loader wherein you can keep the `count`, this will refrain you from adding the HUD again:

```
class Loader {
    private static var count = 0
    
    class func showHUD() {
        if count == 0 {
            print("Add HUD")
            count += 1
        }
    }
    
    class func hideHUD() {
        if count > 0 {
            print("Hide HUD")
            count -= 1
        }
    }
}
```